# **The** word for the military action of shooting several targets at once

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In the Maersk Alabama hijacking, the seals took three shots at once, killing all three pirates simultaneously. I was watching the reproduction and I remember the analyst naming a specific term.

What is the word for that particular action?

Comment: Likely SEALs and re-enactment.

Comment: ["M-M-M-MONSTER-KILL... Kill... Kill"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnJ9k_Im_5w)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMvGIqa-ZlM), the words *simultaneous* and *synchronized shots* are used. However, I believe the correct term is ***[Simultaneous Engagement](http://www.bevfitchett.us/sniper-training-2/simultaneous-engagements.html)***, as seen here quoted from the book *Advanced Sniper Markmanship*, which I believe was written by an instructor in this field.

> ***Simultaneous Engagements***
>
> In certain situations, it's useful for several snipers to ***simultaneously engage*** the same target or multiple targets...

Comment: There it is. Exact match.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it was **time on target**, defined by [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/time%20on%20target)
as

> A concentration of artillery fire on a target in which the time of firing by each unit participating is so regulated that all the projectiles reach the target simultaneously

Comment: From Military Terms.net:  time on target — 1. Time at which aircraft are scheduled to attack/photograph the target. 2.The actual time at which aircraft attack/photograph the target. 3. The time at which a nuclear detonation as planned at a specified desired ground zero. Also called TOT.(JP 3-09.3)

Comment: @Gandalf But what he defined is also true. I've read it in biographies. Same words. Verbatim.

Comment: @vickyace I know the term exists: I found it here: http://www.militaryterms.info/about/glossary-f.shtml   ;but in your bios was it used in the context of sniping?

Comment: @Gandalf I wasn't talking about sniping. I thought that you meant what *Rome_Leader* defined was wrong. I was merely defending the definition.

Comment: @vickyace OK, gotcha. Different branches of the Armed Forces use the same phrases to indicate different operations: for example, flyers have another definition for "simultaneous engagement" - "The concurrent engagement of hostile targets by combination of interceptor aircraft and surface-to-air missiles".

Answer (score 1):

A sniper's shot that kills more than one target is called a *Quigley*.

The term comes from the 1990 film *Quigley Down Under*, in which the eponymous character dispatches multiple opponents with a single shot

[This](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1366154/British-sniper-kills-Taliban-bullet-new-book-reveals.html) newspaper article, and [this](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/books/8376808/Dead-Men-Risen-The-snipers-story.html) one refers to the term.